# Utterance labeling is missing after the migration from Azure LUIS to Conventional Language Understanding Services

Tags: azure, prediction, azure-language-understanding

The model works fine with the existing LUIS model.
The LUIS utterances are well labelled with the entitles in List (i.e. Companies) with values (i.e. Amazon, Microsoft, IBM, etc.)
However, the migrated utterances in Conversational Language Understanding services cannot identify the values in the List which can make the prediction worst than the old LUIS model.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue after migration...